# Visual Basic: i have a file containg usernames and passwords but i want to read them back in so the user can log back in

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Do
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Create a password. It must be 8 characters in length")
        password1 = Console.ReadLine()

    Loop Until password1.Length = 8
    Console.WriteLine("Please re-enter the password.")
    password2 = Console.ReadLine()
Loop Until password2 = password1
password = password1
Console.WriteLine("your password has been created.")    
Console.ReadLine()
```

The below code generates the file

```
Dim fileName = "C:\Users\emily\Documents\Details.csv"
Dim fileAppend As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, True)
fileAppend.WriteLine(name & ", " & age & ", " & username & ", " & password & ", " & yeargroup)
fileAppend.Close()
```

So basically I have details about the users stored in a csv file. The columns are arranged as follows:  name, age, username, password, yeargroup. I need to be able to input a username and for it to be found in the array/list and then input the password and if the password doesn't match for it to start again.

Comment: What's the problem? What's your question?

Comment: Are you really saving plain-text passwords to a text file? That would be a huge security hole.

Comment: You have chosen a wise username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice homework. You should think about storing password. Clear text is obviously risky. With the user file load in a table like this will let you manage all of the user. Add,Remove, Change then just save over the userfile.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim UserTable As New DataTable("UserTable")
    Dim SomeUserName As String = "slims"
    Dim SomePassword As String = "abc1234!"
    Sub ReadUserFile()
        Dim fileName = "C:\dump\test.csv"
        Dim fileReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fileName)
        UserTable.Columns.Add("Name")
        UserTable.Columns.Add("Age")
        UserTable.Columns.Add("Username")
        UserTable.Columns.Add("Password")
        UserTable.Columns.Add("YearGroup")
        Do Until fileReader.EndOfStream = True
            Dim OneLine As String = fileReader.ReadLine()
            UserTable.Rows.Add(OneLine.Split(","))
        Loop
        fileReader.Close()
    End Sub
    Sub WriteUserFile()
        Dim fileName = "C:\dump\test.csv"
        Dim fileWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName)
        For Each xRow As DataRow In UserTable.Rows
            fileWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", xRow("Name"), xRow("Age"), xRow("Username"), xRow("Password"), xRow("YearGroup")))
        Next
        fileWriter.Close()
    End Sub

    Function CheckUserPassword(UserName As String, Password As String) As Boolean
        Dim Found As Boolean = False
        For Each xRow As DataRow In UserTable.Rows
            If (xRow("Username") = SomeUserName) And (xRow("Password") = SomePassword) Then
                Found = True
                Exit For
            Else
                Found = False
            End If
        Next
        Return Found
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ReadUserFile()
        If CheckUserPassword(SomeUserName, SomePassword) = True Then
            'Good to go
        Else
            'bad user/pass
        End If
        WriteUserFile()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)` to read the lines into an array of strings. Then you can use `String.Split()` on each line to split the fields and pick out the username and password.

```
dim allLines as String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
for each line as String in allLines
 dim lineArray() as string
 lineArray = line.Split(New Char() {","c})
 username = lineArray(2)
 password = lineArray(3)
 if username = theUsernameYouWant then
  'Found the user. Now check their password
 endif
next
```

I havn't tested this code. Might have syntax errors.

Comment: Let's hope the users don't have any commas in their passwords.

Comment: This program seems to be a toy/school exercise because it's riddled with edge case bugs, so I think they'll ignore that.

Comment: Yes, that's probably fair enough. It'd be great to know what the requirements were for this assignment.